# How do I retain layout integrity when using UIScrollView in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I am working in Storyboard with a Navigation View Controller and a view Controller that displays detail content. This requires UIScrollView. In order to extend the content and enable the scroll view I had to disable Use Autolayout in the File Inspector. When I do this though the content layout breaks in the Simulator and on the iPhone. If I enable Use Autolayout the layout is fine, but the scrolling is disabled.

Here is the code I am using in the ViewController.m

```
[self.myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.myScrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, 900))];
```

Here are screen shots of the Storyboard layout and the resulting simulator view:

[image]
[image]

I am eager to know how to resolve this dilemma.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have at least one constraint between the top edge of the scroll view and one of its subviews, and at least one constraint between the bottom edge of the scroll view and one of its subviews.  Auto layout will use these constraints to set the content size of the scroll view.

You can find more information in [Tech Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

You might also find [my screencast about scroll views in Interface Builder](http://youtu.be/PgeNPRBrB18) helpful.

Comment: Hi Rob, excellent solution and thank you for the link to your screencast. I'll definitely be digging deeper on that.